# How can I get pinterest pin button show zerocount for current page

Tags: javascript, html, social-networking, pinterest

Basically I need Pinterest button with counts beside to it even if the count is zero. I have got facebook, google, twitter and linked in doing this why not Pinterest?

Following is the code I am using to render the Pinterest button, I have tried alot but may be I am missing something simple
The config I am using is data-pin-config='beside' data-pin-do='buttonPin'
href="//pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=currentpage&media=http%3A%2F%2Ffarm8.staticflickr.com%2F7027%2F6851755809_df5b2051c9_z.jpg&guid=bj5u2KMfSVWK&media=http%3A%2F%2Ffarm8.staticflickr.com%2F7027%2F6851755809_df5b2051c9_z.jpg"
script src='http:// assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js'

Sorry I had to get rid of html tags as it was playing and not showing in the question

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Pinterest ever shows zero you go from no number to the number one.

Answer (score 0):

By default Pinterest does not show zero counts but you can enable it with the attribute `data-pin-zero`:

```html
<a href="..." data-pin-zero="true" data-pin-config="beside" data-pin-do="buttonPin">...</a>
```

Although I could not find anything about this on developers.pinterest.com, it can be found in their [js-file on github](https://github.com/pinterest/widgets/blob/master/pinit_main.js#L775).